# GNU sed --posix and newline character in replacement string

Tags: sed, posix, newlines

In the POSIX `sed` specification [this statement](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) is to be found (my emphasis):

> The escape sequence '\n' shall match a <newline> embedded in the
>   pattern space. *A literal <newline> shall not be used* in the BRE of a
>   context address or *in the substitute function.*

The following GNU `sed` command with `--posix` flag is contrary to that specification, because a newline is used in the substitute function.

```
$ printf '1X2' | sed --posix 's|X|\n|'
1
2
```

So why did `sed` insert a newline instead of giving an error message?

Comment: You're reading it wrong. The section your quote from is _Regular Expressions in sed_  and it specifically says that a _literal newline_  shouldn't be used in a BRE. The right hand side of a substitution is not a regular expression, that is the left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

"A literal <newline> shall not be used", 
There is no literal newline used in your example. Therefore this part of the standard is not relevant.

`\n` is **not** a literal newline.

Comment: Actually, in the above example, using _a literal newline_ (preceded by a backslash) instead of `\n` is the POSIX way to do it ;)

Comment: OP, you have accepted an answer that doesn't answer your question...

Comment: @don_crissti Really? I think I just missed the vocabulary distinction between a literal newline and a \n escape sequence, which was clarified in this answer. Why do you think it does not answer my question?

Comment: @Quasímodo - If you read my comment on your Q again, you (just like the author of this answer) miss the distinction between LHS and RHS of a substitution.According to this answer, your code works because you used `\n` and not a literal newline _which is false_ - in fact, as I said above, the proper way to use newlines in the replacement string is to insert them _literally_ preceded by a backslash (it's in the standard by the way). Now, if your Q is "why does `\n` work in the RHS with gnu sed?" that is a different Q and has nothing to do with the quote about regex from the standard.

Comment: Someone should add a correct answer, so that I can vote it up.

Comment: I have trimed my answer. I believe the first part was correct ( I have added some clarity to it). The 2nd part was probably not (and was not needed), so I removed it. The 3rd part is also correct and clear (so left unchanged).

Answer (score 2):

The `--posix` flag makes GNU `sed` POSIX compliant.

POSIX leaves the behaviour for `s/x/\n/` unspecified:

> The meaning of an unescaped <backslash> immediately followed by any character other than '&', <backslash>, a digit, <newline>, or the delimiter character used for this command, is unspecified.

So replacing `x` with `n`, with `\n`, with newline, reporting an error, reboot your computer are all compliant behaviours. There's no reason why GNU `sed` would want to change its behaviour there.

A conforming *application* (i.e., script in that case) must not use `\n` there, that's what the text you quote is about.

It's different in `s/[\t]/x/g` where POSIX requires it to replace both `\` and `t` with `x`, and you'll see the behaviour of GNU `sed` changes with `--posix` there. For `s/[\n]/x/g`, the POSIX specification is actually ambiguous. GNU `sed` changes its behaviour with `--posix` so that it replaces `\` and `n` with `x`, but it's not so clear whether it needs to or not.

Answer (score 1):

The standard specifies that in the *search pattern* (BRE, Basic Regular Expression, in POSIX-speak) no explicit newline can be used, and that there a newline is represented by '\n'; and it can't be used in the *replacement* either.

Your search pattern doesn't include any newlines, explicit or represented by '\n'. You have a '\n' in the replacement. The above doesn't say how a newline is to be represented (if at all) in the replacement text. GNU sed takes the previous as saying replacing by '\n' means introducing a newline. Sensible.

Comment: _"and it can't be used in the replacement either."_ that's also wrong.

Comment: @don_crissti, the standard is wrong?

Comment: Where exactly does the standard say that "it can't be used in the replacement either" ? That's your interpretation which, again, is wrong.